# jquery click function does not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

I have a asp.net web application written in VS 2013. The application has nested master pages and main master page has following codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My web form consists of following codes also:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#textbox1').click(function () {
                alert('Hello');
            });
        });
    </script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50" runat="server">
</div>
```

And when I build the project and run on browser (either ie or chrome), I click on "textbox1" and browser does nothing.

Appreciate for help.

Comment: </script> tag was forgotten at the moment cut and paste.. apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
$('#textbox1')
```

with this:

```
$('#<%=textbox1.ClientID%>')
```

Your textbox is a server side control. So you have to read the `ClientID`, in order to read the ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET. For further info please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx). Generally as it is stated in the previous link:

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id
>   attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID
>   property

Furthermore, you have to remove the closing `script` tag, `</script>`, just before the opening `script` tag, `<script>` of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `</script>` tag immediately after your asp tag.

Try the same code without it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#textbox1').click(function () {
                alert('Hello');
            });
        });
    </script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" maxlength="50" runat="server">
</div>
```

Works for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/mutjg5sq/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it help you

Script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Html:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
     $('#textbox1').click(function () {
                    alert('Hello');
                });
</script>
```